# Printing a '$' (dollar sign) to a file

Tags: scripting, command-line-interface, escaping

I want to `echo`/`printf` a dollar sign into a file - but `echo $ > myfile` or such does not work (not surprising).

I tried escaping it like `echo \$ > myfile` but it is also not working.

What is the correct way to perform it?

I'm working with TCSH on SunOs.

Comment: The escaped version worked on my site (on Linux as well as on SunOS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use printf and single quotes to avoid variable expansion:

```
printf '$' > myfile
```

Comment: Erm, why would you choose printf to echo a static string?

Comment: @jgoldschrafe: Because I'm sure the Solaris printf command will be used in that case so I can avoid whatever oddity tcsh echo builtin might introduce.

Answer (score 2):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005963/how-can-i-have-a-newline-in-a-string-in-sh) link, you can use the \x24 method, where 24 is the hex for the dollar sign.
Just that this structure doesn't work 100% with string using the double quote, so you probably want to use a single quote.
So this statement

```
echo "Foo "$'\x24'" bar" >> somefile
```

will create somefile with the content

```
Foo $ bar
```

**Note:** tcsh (name dropped in the original question) does not support dollar-quote literals (like `$'\x24'`).  Nor does dash.  It is not a POSIX standardized feature.